# My table has one column with datatype as int but now I have decided to change it into float

Tags: java, hibernate

My table has one column with datatype as int but now I have decided to change it into float. so I changed my pojo from into to float . But i cannot see the changes in my table as it is still showing column with int dataype. How can i do this from my code.

Comment: please provide some of your current code

Comment: Is the class you made the change in a POJO or a JPA Entity? How is the configuration in your `persistence.xml` for the property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`? please add more Infos to your question to make it more clear.

Comment: I have changed into my POJO . I am new to java dont know much about this

Comment: I got this in my persistance.xml for the property hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto        <property name ="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

Comment: @ruhungry : not totally new.

Comment: to answer your question with the provided info, i would say the change you did will have no effect. Please add the code of the so called "POJO" to your question. And if you search a bit more for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` you will find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15978368/1113392) which most likely will explain the problem you are facing.

Comment: currently it is having value="update"

Comment: I am not getting why the schema is not updated . since i changed in POJO

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```sql
-- AlterTable
ALTER TABLE `Recipe` MODIFY `totalServings` FLOAT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1;

-- AlterTable
ALTER TABLE `RecipeIngredient` MODIFY `servingAmount` FLOAT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0
```

Warnings:

- You are about to alter the column `totalServings` on the `Recipe` table. The data in that column could be lost. The data in that column will be cast from `Int` to `Double`.
- You are about to alter the column `servingAmount` on the `RecipeIngredient` table. The data in that column could be lost. The data in that column will be cast from `Int` to `Double`.