# How to make an optional/nullable property in hibernate-validator?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

I found this [implementation](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-811) that basically do what I want.

```
@ConstraintComposition(OR)
@NotBlank
@Null
@ReportAsSingleViolation
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
public @interface NullOrNotBlank {
    String message() default "{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NullOrNotBlank.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

and I use it as

```
@field:NullOrNotBlank
@field:Size(max = 50)
var middleName: String? = null,
```

I've also tried

```
@field:NullOrNotBlank
@field:Size(max = 50)
@field:Column(nullable = true)
var middleName: String? = null,
```

But this composite constraints makes the field in the database (MySQL) not nullable. So what happens is that it's working fine until I save the Entity to the database.

Comment: The generated column of `NullOrNotBlank` is `NOT NULL` which throws an error when I'm inserting an entity with null property

Comment: hi, I think you try to using `hbm2ddl.auto` to update the constraint in an column. if the column exists, it doesn't update the constraints at all. so you should update it manually. please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978368/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-update-doesnt-update-column-definitions-in-mysql/26681592

Comment: how about it now? if there is no problem. you should delete your question, since it is duplicated.

Comment: I'm using hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop to recreate the tables at startup

Comment: are you sure? have you using `@Column(nullable = true)` on your column field? the `@NullOrNotBlank` is only for validating and don't support for the  column definition.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried it. You can read my question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I embedded the `hibernate-validator` my [tests](https://github.com/holi-java/api-tests/blob/d52f6d2a3cbed3479d146e65efdb65892cfe9a91/hibernate/jpa/src/test/kotlin/test/DDLAutoGenerationTest.kt#L51) also failed too.

> **Why** did the *nullable* column is changed to *non-nullable* column by `hibernate-validator`?

the `hibernate-validator` will makes the column to **non-nullable** column, if you declared any **non-nullable** constraints on the column, for example:

```
@[ConstraintComposition(OR) NotBlank Null]
//                          ^---- it is a @NotNull constraint

@NotNull
public @interface NotBlank {...}
```

> **How** to solve this problem?

**IF** you have seen my [tests](https://github.com/holi-java/api-tests/blob/d52f6d2a3cbed3479d146e65efdb65892cfe9a91/hibernate/jpa/src/test/kotlin/test/DDLAutoGenerationTest.kt#L51) on github, you maybe found that I used a `@Length` which is a **nullable** constraint, then the `hibernate-validator` doesn't change the original column definition at all, for example:

```
@[ConstraintComposition(OR)  Length(min = 1)  Null]
//it is a nullable constraint ---^
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What I did on my implementation is that I've replaced `@Length` with `@Size(min = 1)` so that it would be applicable to other data types.

Comment: I've also noticed that my old implementation ignores the `@NotBlank` constraint. Because after I had changed it to `@Size(min = 1)`  some test that asserts the number of violation failed.

Comment: @jasperagrante Not at all. I found that `hibernate-validator` will change the `DDL` definition last night.

Comment: I've also already implemented Flyway on my application so I would have control on the Schema and Migrations. Thanks again :)