# Hibernate doesn't add new columns to tables on hbm2ddl.auto="update"

Tags: hibernate, hql

Dears,

I have multiple tables and I need to add extra columns in each, I added them entity classes but hibernate stilldoesn't create them, I even tried to use the added columns in hql queries but it gives an error that property doesn't exist.

Columns I want to add:

```
@Column (name = "CREATED_BY")
    private String createdBy;

    private String active;
```

I retrieved an object and tried to print the value of active. it said this propery doesn't exist.

```
#{obj.active}
```

Comment: It is already answered, please refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978368/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-update-doesnt-update-column-definitions-in-mysql

Comment: @srinivas it's not, the link you gave says that having "update" would solve the issue but it's not. I mean I have the "update" but still the columns are not added

Comment: @Code des can you show us the annotations of the entity class itself? I mean annotations such as _@Table_

Comment: Hei, do you find a solution? :)

Answer (score 1):

@Code des 
It just hit me. Did you happen to forget the `setters` for the new fields? If that is the case, try to add the setters for the fields (maybe also `getters`). Make those `private` if you don't want other business logic to change the fields. 
Also, you mentioned you're using Hibernate 3 and there's no `@CreationTimeStamp`(I haven't got time to check if that's true), then I wonder how come you didn't get compile error when using an unexisting annotation??

Answer (score 0):

You have not added hibernate property to active variable

@Column (name = "active")

private String active;

Comment: I don't think you need to add the annotation there. `@Column` annotation is needed only when you want to change default setting, say, column name and length.

Comment: hi..Isaac_Zhu, but how hibernate/jpa can map/create active column in database without @Column annotation. Because of this it gives error(property doesn't exist). There is no column(active) found in database.

Comment: JPA (Java Pesistence API, Hibernate implements JPA) will create a default definition of the table column for each field according to the field name and the type, unless the field is explicitly marked with @Transient. In this case, it will be same as if you put @Column(name=“active”).

Comment: @Isaac_Zhu can the JPA be the reason why creationtimestamp annotation doesn't work ?

Comment: @Codedes are you asking something different? Do you mind posting a more complete version of your entity? 
`@CreationTimestamp` works if configured correctly, also it's good to set the `updatable = false` for the corresponding field so it won't be accidentally updated.

Comment: @Isaac_Zhu for creationtimestamo, I have hibernate 3 and seems it's not on that version